# Create a PowerPoint file using PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, com

I need to find a way to create (or modify a pre-created ) PowerPoint file using PHP. Looking on the web I find the class COM but I am having some problem with that. I am using Ubuntu 14 (with LAMPP) and I added the few lines to make it works, as said in this page ([Class 'COM' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678325/class-com-not-found)) but nothing seems to change. I would ask if there is something else that I can make so class COM will work or another way to create and/or modify a PowerPoint file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're using Ubuntu, so can't use COM with MS PowerPoint, have you tried [PHPPowerPoint](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPowerPoint) which doesn't have any dependency on MS Office?

An alternative would be to use [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/?do=0a,01,05) with Libre/Open Office Impress