# Class 'COM' not found occures in one php file but in another it works

Tags: php, shell

I have two `.php` files in the same folder.
And in both of these files I have the following code.

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
```

in the first file it works fine, because My php version is the latest and I've changed my `php.ini` file so that I could use this command.
But I get  `Class 'COM' not found` error when I use this code in the second `.php`.

In first file

```
define('PHP_EXE', 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.29\php.exe');
define('PHP_DIR', 'C:\wamp\www\AugSow\augsow1\service');
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");   
$command= "\"".PHP_EXE."\" ".PHP_DIR."\copy_to_conversion_server.php filePath=\"".$filePath."\" docId=".$docId."";
$oExec = $WshShell->Run($command, 0, false);
```

The command in the first file executes another `.php` file called `init_symplygon.php`
And in this file I have the following code

```
 define('PHP_EXE', 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.29\php.exe');
 define('PHP_DIR', 'C:\wamp\www\AugSow\augsow1\service');
 $command= "\"".PHP_EXE."\" ".PHP_DIR."\init_symplygon.php filePath=\"".$filePath."\" docId=".$docId."";
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");   
$oExec = $WshShell->Run($command, 0, false);
```

Here I get the error.

What can be the reason of such kind of behavior?

Comment: Possible Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678325/class-com-not-found

Comment: First of all I've searched and found your referenced post. And changed my  `php.ini` as I mentioned in my post. The problem is` in one file I get this error, but in another one it works fine.

Comment: Have you restarted your server after?

Comment: I've just tried it . But  I still have the same error

Comment: Wouldn't you think it makes more sense to let on some details about the two distinct php files? Rather than let us guess for possible SAPI/runtime differences? -- Things you have tried or questions found beforehand should be listed in the question as well. It's somewhat unproductive to ask for suggestions, than answer each and every one of them with "Oops, yes, tried that already" afterwards.

Comment: "mario" You're right, I've added some details please look if there are any details you would like to see in the post.

Comment: "Karen" That doesn't yet explain how/where both scripts are invoked. Patch in `phpinfo()` to figure out the distinct execution contexts.