# how to use COM class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

How can I use Com Class in Laravel?

in my controller:

```
$mp = new \COM('{Name}');
```

my error:
Class 'COM' not found

i want use this class in Laravel:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

Comment: How do you use the `com` class? Did you put global name space i.e: `$variable = new \com('...')`?

Comment: $mp = new \COM("{name}"); i define like this but i don't have class !

Comment: i have this error now: Class 'COM' not found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class 'COM' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678325/class-com-not-found)

Comment: i use php 7.3 and laravel 7 . but without laravel it's work! in a simple php project but dose not work in laravel!